# Use TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider class in Silverlight Application

Tags: .net, silverlight, cryptography, tripledes

I use a web service to authenticate. And this web service use the TripleDes algorithm to encrypt to user name and password. Im my silverlight application I have to encrypt  these value for calling web service but I can not add reference of System.Security.Cryptography dll.

How can I use this dll file for Silverlight application?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a `System.Security.Cryptography` dll.

`System.Security.Cryptography` is a namespace present in several assemblies that Microsoft ships. In case of `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` the type is present inside `mscorlib.dll`.

Sadly Silverlight profile does not ship with `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` inside it's own (minimal) `mscorlib.dll` (or inside any other assembly).

However you can get a fully compatible (and 100% managed) version of [3DES](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.cs) from the Mono project (MIT X.11 licensed). You simply have to add the source file (and other files it depends on) to your own project, rebuild and use it like the *normal* desktop .NET framework.

Comment: You suggest me to use .net application for using TripleDES but I have to use Silverlight Application  and for encrypt user name and password I have to use TripleDES. For looking I read taht I must wirte my class in the . net assembly and change it to silverlight dll file. And I find [this.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32639/Converting-NET-Assemblies-to-Silverlight-Assemblie) This article explain how I could change the dll file.

Comment: No. I suggest you to copy/paste the `TripleDES` **source code** (from the Mono project) into your **own** Silverlight application, then use it and re-compile **your** application.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I tried  that you are suggested. But I could not find the Mono.Security.Cryptography dll. Could you help?

Comment: `Mono.Security.Cryptography` is a namespace, not an assembly (and can't be since `mscorlib.dll` cannot depend on other assemblies). Browse the source code (from the link I gave in the answer) and you'll find a directory (with that name) above, but still inside, the `corlib` directory.