# Extending .NET TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I need to use the TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider in c# with a weak key. I am trying to work around based on the suggestion found in MSDN and also couple of other posts over here as follows.

**Edit: It seems I was looking for something that does not exist. `_NewEncryptor` is not compiled in if compiled for `Mono`. The answer provided by @John is correct.**

**Edit: As pointed out by @John in the answer, I have refactored the code. But the problem is not resolved yet.**

```
public static class TripleDESCryptoServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static ICryptoTransform CreateWeakEncryptor(this TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        MethodInfo mi = cryptoProvider.GetType().GetMethod("_NewEncryptor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object[] Par = { key, cryptoProvider.Mode, iv, cryptoProvider.FeedbackSize, 1 };
        var trans = mi.Invoke(cryptoProvider, Par) as ICryptoTransform;
        return trans;
    }

    public static ICryptoTransform CreateWeakEncryptor(this TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider)
    {
        return CreateWeakEncryptor(cryptoProvider, cryptoProvider.Key, cryptoProvider.IV);
    }
}
```

But,

`cryptoProvider.GetType().GetMethod("_NewEncryptor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);`

returns null. Any suggestions?

Comment: `private ICryptoTransform _NewEncryptor(byte[] rgbKey, CipherMode mode, byte[] rgbIV, int feedbackSize, CryptoAPITransformMode encryptMode)` from TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider. This is private method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using the wrong method name. You're specifying `_NewDecryptor`, but the method is actually called `_NewEncryptor`. Making that change resolves the method.

However, if I've misunderstood, and you really are looking for a `_NewDecryptor` method, it [does not exist](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/tripledescryptoserviceprovider.cs).

That said, there is one other issue with your code: it causes a `StackOverflowException`, because you're calling the method recursively. I'm guessing you meant:

```
return trans;
```

instead.

Edit: Here's a sample console application that gives the expected result.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace _51915147
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            var weakEncryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateWeakEncryptor();


        }
    }

    public static class TripleDESCryptoServiceProviderExtensions
    {
        public static ICryptoTransform CreateWeakEncryptor(this TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            MethodInfo mi = cryptoProvider.GetType().GetMethod("_NewEncryptor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            object[] Par = { key, cryptoProvider.Mode, iv, cryptoProvider.FeedbackSize, 1 };
            var trans = mi.Invoke(cryptoProvider, Par) as ICryptoTransform;
            return trans;
        }

        public static ICryptoTransform CreateWeakEncryptor(this TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider)
        {
            return CreateWeakEncryptor(cryptoProvider, cryptoProvider.Key, cryptoProvider.IV);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This was a .NET Framework console application targeting version 4.7.1 of the framework.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake while copying the code. But, the revised code still fails as `getMethod()` returns null.

Comment: @fossil It works perfectly for me. I created a console application targeting .NET 4.7.1.

Comment: As you pointed out, it works fine in .NET 4.7.1; I am using this code in Xamarin Mono Android 8.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: @fossil If you take a look at the [Mono source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/tripledescryptoserviceprovider.cs) you'll see `_NewEncryptor` is only defined when _not_ built as Mono, which is why it's `null` for you. If you look at the `CreateEncryptor` method, you'll see it will always return a new `TripleDESTransform`.

Comment: @fossil [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11493127/729541) answer mentions using `3DES` but that also may not be an option for you. Worst case scenario would be copying some code into your project.

Comment: You are right. I am relatively new to C# and .NET/Mono platforms. As of now, I am using BouncyCastle, which works fine. I was trying to avoid an external library if possible. I will checkout mono source.

Comment: I took a peek in mono sources to see if I can extend over override. It seems TripleDESTransform is internal class. I am new to reflection and not sure how to go about.